# Salvage SVN repository from dead Windows Server 2003

Tags: svn, windows-server-2003, import

I cannot start the server but I can access the file system (I connected the hard drive by SATA-to-USB to on my laptop) and I want to transfer the repository to new installation (I use win32svn server on Windows 2003).

I read some articles how can I migrate SVN repository to another server but they all say that I should run a `svnadmin dump/hotcopy` command first, but I cannot do that because I cannot boot the OS.

Answer (score 4):

The commands are recommended because if you copy the repository's files *while subversion is running* then you risk copying the repository in an invalid state.

Since the server is dead, you can just copy the repo.

Comment: Of course, take care to use the same version of the SVN server that was installed on the old system. Sometimes the repo format changes from version to version.

Comment: @sleske: A *newer* version of Subversion should be fine... Older formats are always supported.

Comment: @sleske - as haimug says, you can use svnadmin upgrade to make the repository the required format for the latest version (whether local or remote repositories) - see http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svnadmin.c.upgrade.html